# What does additive mean in "additive basis" in algebraic geometry?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $Gr(k,n)$ be the set of all $k$-dimensional subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space. I heard that people say "an additive basis" of $\mathbb{C}[Gr(k,n)]$. What does additive mean? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An additive basis is a basis as a vector space (or more often free abelian group)  as opposed to perhaps a generating set as an algebra. The latter is not usually called a basis, and "additive" is really used for emphasis here.